# Логирование ошибок telebot в журнал journald

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, логирование, uvicorn

Есть бот, построенный на вебхуках. В качестве отладки ошибок используется `journald` (`journalctl`).

Бот построен на `uvicorn`, и веб-сервер вызывается непосредственно из точки входа "__main__". Там же я и указываю параметром, что нужно выводить все логи в журнал.

Иногда, когда бот выводит предупреждение, по типу что сообщение для редактирования не было найдено, или не был, к примеру, найден файл с таким идентификатором -  то в консоли `PyCharm` обычно появлялось красное предупреждение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Да и когда бот работал на `getUpdates` на сервере - эти предупреждения показывались в журнале. А после того как я поднял веб-сервер - данные сообщения не отображаются в журнале, что и есть для меня проблемой.

Журнал смотрю командой `journalctl -u bot --since=-1h`

```
...
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    # bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    uvicorn.run(app=app,
                host=config.HOST,
                port=config.PORT,
                access_log=True,
                # log_level='info', - это выводит всю информацию, но не предупреждения
                ssl_keyfile='pkey.pem',
                ssl_certfile='cert.pem')
```

Я пробовал указывать запуск `systemd` `bot.service` с флагом

`ExecStart=/usr/lib/python3 -u /home/myname/bot/bot_example.py`

но предупреждение до сих пор не выводится в логах.

Что можно предпринять? Я хочу, чтоб предупреждения выводились ИМЕННО в журнал `journalctl`.

UPD.

Я уже пробовал и такой способ:

```
import logging
from telebot import logger
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('log.txt'))
```

В `PyCharm` на Windows результат записывается в файл, а вот на сервере `Ubuntu` - нет. С чем связано такое логирование?

Пробовал добавлять и `flush` к `sys.stderr` в логгере в исходниках `pytelegrambotapi` - безрезультатно

UPD2.
Нашел способ добавить логгер непосредственно в `uvicorn`, но работает он только в режиме `DEBUG`, а вот в режиме `ERROR` почему-то пропускает ошибки. Как это можно решить?

```
log_config = uvicorn.config.LOGGING_CONFIG
log_config['loggers'].update({"TeleBot": {"handlers": ["access"], "level": "ERROR"}})
```

Comment: Еее., наконец-то! Почти 10 часов попыток, и половину перелопаченного интернета дали хорошие плоды:)

Comment: Как оказалось - без вмешательства в исходный код библиотеки `pytelegrambotapi` решить проблему не удастся, но проблема решается довольно просто